# Get Video or Video Info Without open Gallery Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype

I am trying to get Video without open `Gallery` or `UIImagePickerController`like I got success in getting images without open gallery. Is there any way to get files without open `UIImagePickerController`.

Can someone please explain to me how to get files without open UIImagePickerController. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, using the following code, you can get the latest user video:

```
import Photos

let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.fetchLimit = 1
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
options.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: options)
if fetchResult.count == 0 {
    // user has no video...
    return
}
let asset = fetchResult[0]
let requestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
let manager = PHImageManager.default()
```

Then, if you want to get the video itself, use the following code:

```
manager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { oAsset, oAudioMix, oDict in
    if let urlAsset = oAsset as? AVURLAsset {
        let url = urlAsset.url
        // use URL to get file content
    }
})
```

Otherwise, if you just want to play the video, use the following code:

```
manager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { oPlayerItem, oDict in
    // do something with oPlayerItem
})
```

For more information you can read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager#1656266)